# Http Methods in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, http, get, getmethod

I've been looking for answers for the past days and still I haven't got any idea on how can I make my app work. I only have one controller for all the subtabs of my app. I had one http get method for one subtab under the main controller and I need another http get method for another subtab to also be under the main controller. How can I possibly do that?

Comment: can you send your code what you done ?

Comment: you can call multiple get method in one controller and assign to variables

Comment: @VipinJain how?if it is not too much, can you show me in plunker?thanks

Comment: yes i show but your code there are no tab or subtab. you only create a controller and inside you call a get method thats it

Comment: can you show me how can I assign http get method into variables? @VipinJain

Comment: you can assign in variable but you say  'I need another http get method for another subtab to also be under the main controller' so you can call one other http get method and asign to a variable like you done in example `var json = $.xml2json(data);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100210/discussion-between-bleykfaust-and-vipin-jain).

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute routing.

```
      [HttpGet]
      [Route("method1/{id}")]
      public HttpResponseMessage index(string id) 
     {
        try
        {
           // your code
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,ex.Message);
       }
     }

         [HttpGet]
         [Route("method2/{Id}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetData(string GetRecordsById) 
          {
               try
                   {
                  //your code
                    }
               catch (Exception)
                  {
                     throw;
                     }
             }
```

Comment: Thanks @MahavirKumbharvadia but I think this is not angularjs?